# How do I allow for more than one answer to be 'true' in my conditional?

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

```
# Declare variables

answer=''

answer = (input("Do you know how to build a computer?"))
if answer == "yes":
print("Yes, I know how to build a computer.")
else:
    print("Oh, sorry for bothering you.")

print("Sucess.")
```

My code works as intended as it's written, but my problem comes when I try to add other accepted answers.

What I thought I needed to allow for multiple 'true' conditionals was:

```
if answer == "yes" or "Yes" or "y" or "Y":
```

But this will just result in every answer being 'true' and no input being 'false'.

I apologize if this seems a bit confused. I'm still quite new to coding and I haven't quite gotten the terminology down yet.

Comment: `if answer.lower() in {'yes', 'y'}`... as `bool('Yes')` is `True` your if statement will always be true...

Answer (score 1):

As @hiro mentioned in the comments you can use `in` keyword. The `.lower()` will convert input string into lower case so that you won't need to include upper case responses.

```
answer=''

answer = (input("Do you know how to build a computer?"))
if answer.lower() in ("yes","y"):
    print("Yes, I know how to build a computer.")
else:
    print("Oh, sorry for bothering you.")

print("Success.")
```